# Underline persists despite 'text-decoration: none'

Tags: html, css

I do want there to be a half underline on hover. That is demonstrated in the fiddle using the `:before` pseudo. I do not want there to be an extra underline when the link is clicked.

The obvious answer is set

```
a {text-decoration: none}
```

This does not work. It works fine in the fiddle, but not applied here.

Here is my navbar:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><h1 ><a id="name" href="#">y o u r &nbsp;N A M E</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">W O R K S</a></h1></li>
    <li><h1><a href="#">A B O U T</a></h1></li>
</ul>
</nav
```

and all CSS pertaining to `a` tags on this navbar:

```
a {
color: black;
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
position: relative;
font-size: .4em;
}

nav a:hover::before{
position: absolute;
bottom: -10px;
left: 25%;
right: 25%;
height: 1px;
background: #7b0700;
content: "";
}

 a:active,  a:visited {
border-bottom: 0 !important ;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: #7b0700;
}

a:active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7b0700;
    }
```

A JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ljvd2u06/9/

Why would this work in the fiddle but not in application? What can I do to make it disappear on my site?

Thanks.

Comment: Tested on safari & firefox just now and it works properly - only one half underline, make sure to close the `<nav>` element in your html also, and remove the extra space in the first `<h1>` element

Comment: There is possibly another rule in your full CSS that is overriding the rule posted above. Try this: `a { text-decoration: none !important; }` as a test, then you'll know.

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: It's likely to be styled by a more specific css rule than just `a { ... }`. You can use developers tools to find out what's going on and override the css without `!important`

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a simple `position: static;` in my answer below.

Comment: @DrewKennedy, thank you. Didn't think to use the inspector. Bootstrap includes the `outline-style` property on links and I was not aware. This fixed it! If you would post it as an answer, I can upvote it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Often using `a:link { }` rather than just `a { }` will correctly set this.